# Need explanation of the error in Oracle LiveSQL

Tags: oracle

I am getting the error - "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" in oracle live sql for the following code. Where am I going wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID int;
CustomerName varchar(255);
ContactName varchar(255);
Address varchar(255);
City varchar(255);
PostalCode int;
Country varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: The error means you have a semicolon after `CustomerID int` thus ending the command way too early. You need commas instead. Moreover there is no type `int` in Oracle. Use `number(8)` (or whichever length you like) instead. In Oracle you'd also rather use their data type `varchar2` instead of `varchar`. I don't know if `varchar` is even supported.

Comment: @Thorsten, INT won't raise an error.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `VARCHAR` is a synonym of `VARCHAR2` (but there is the potential that Oracle may introduce a `VARCHAR` data type that follows the ANSI standard with regard to NULLs in a later version, but it is very unlikely as it would break the backwards compatibility of lots of databases). `INT` is a synonym of `NUMBER(38)`.

Comment: Thanks to you both for clarifying this.

Comment: Thanks everyone that replied. Very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use comma instead of semicolon for each column you want to use in your table

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID int,
CustomerName varchar(255),
ContactName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PostalCode int,
Country varchar(255)
);
```